# Page not found errors for images

Tags: debugging, performance

The site becomes painfully slow at times and when I look into "Recent Log Mesaages" logs such as this is frequently found.
[image: Log message]

The Location shows:

http://example.com/sites/default/files/styles/featured/public/field/image/DPL_1.jpg?itok=JJwFY0A5

The log's Type is "page not found" and occurrence is multiple times every hour. I think this is the reason that is making the site very slow at times.
How to fix it ?

Comment: Is the error always for the same image? Does that image exist? Do you have access to your server's error logs? Are there any entries at the same time?

Comment: Its not the same images but a few images(8 to 10) which are being repeated. Those images  do not exist.

Comment: Everyday new 3-4 images are being added. I believe they are the images which are once uploaded then deleted(replaced with other images).

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, are you able to solve this issue ?